# How do you configure XCode to find header files and symbols in an "External Build System" project

Tags: c, xcode, gnu-make, configure, autoconf

I'm trying to set up an XCode 5.1 project for C php-extension development.  This is essentially a GNU autoconf/automake project with one prerequisite step.

I created a new "External Build System" project.  I then made two targets, one that runs the prerequisite "phpize" command that creates GNU autoconf files.  I have another target that runs the GNU ./configure script.   This all works great.

Next, I tried adding my .c and .h files to the project.  When I open them, and try to click on any #include .h file or any external symbol, XCode says "symbol not found", even for system stuff like <stdio.h>.

In a normal XCode project, there is a way to configure the header/include search paths.  With this external build system project, I see no way to do this.

My questions:

1. For a project that uses ./configure and make, is the "External Build System" project type the correct type?
2. If so, then in this project type, how do I set the header/include search paths so that code navigation works?
3. Analyze doesn't seem to work right, either.

Comment: When the project was created, was the [OS X]->[Application]->[Command Line Tool] template used?

Comment: I had a similar problem and created a dummy target as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484996/how-can-i-enable-xcode-refactor-options-for-an-external-build-project